# How to access Multiple DB2 Relational Databases In A Single Query

Tags: join, db2, db2-luw, authorization, federated-table

I am looking for a solution to the problem described below.

There are two DB2 instances with two authorization IDs on the same server and can be accessed using the same user User1.

**Example:**

To access Inst1DB, I use the following commands:

```
[User1 ~]$ . /db2/authID1db2/home/authID1db2/sqllib/db2profile
[User1 ~]$ db2 connect to Inst1DB
```

To access Inst2DB, run the following commands:

```
[User1 ~]$ . /db2/auth2db2/home/auth2db2/sqllib/db2profile
[User1 ~]$ db2 connect to Inst2DB
```

Note that one needs to terminate the current DB2 session before connecting to another DB instance.
To terminate DB session, run the following command:

```
[User1 ~]$ db2 terminate
```

**Issue:**

I want to join two tables, one of which belongs to INST1DB and the other to INST2DB, while connected to INST1DB.

```
[User1 ~]$ . /db2/authID1db2/home/authID1db2/sqllib/db2profile
[User1 ~]$ db2 connect to Inst1DB
[User1 ~]$ db2 "Select * from Inst1DB.schema1.table1 T1 , Inst2DB.schema2.table2 T2 where T1.column1 = T2.column1.
```

Curerntly I am getting below error:

> SQL0204N  "Inst2DB.schema2.table2" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704.

**Query:**

Can anyone suggest to me how to connect the two instances and perform a join on these tables?

Answer (score 1):

One way you can achieve this is via [federation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.db.found.conn.fw.db2.doc/topics/tlsdb201.html). In short words, if you want to access db_b from db_a, you catalog db_b in instance of db_a. You then create nicknames in db_a for the tables in db_b that you want to access. The nicknames can with some restrictions be treated as tables, so you can join a table in db_a with a table in db_b.

Comment: I can't use this feature as, DBA is not allowing this approach. does it have have impact on system performance? Also, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean overall performance? I don't think so, but the only way to find out is to test it. Other ways to do it, well some kind of replication from db_b to db_a would do.

Comment: Hi Lennart, Thanks for your response. Is this(Federation) way possible when we have 2 DB's in DB2 itself, on same server but with diffrerent authorisation ID. I have gone through Federation Documentation but couldn't find anything for DB2 to DB2 Server connectivity. Everything is related to other Databases like
Informix
Microsoft SQL Server
Oracle
Sybase
Teradata. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.db.found.conn.fw.configgen.doc/topics/tlsgen15.html

Comment: Yes, federation is possible in your case. You use a user mapping

Comment: See the link in my answer, it is a step by step instruction

Comment: Thanks, Will try.